How to control an azhdarchid pterosaur?
In a world with many prehistoric animals that are still around, the giant azhdarchids are one of them. Obviously, the first nation to use them in combat will gain a huge advantage dropping bombs and such, but the issue is that it's not able to carry an adult human rider. My question is, how can the azhdarchid be controlled to fly over the enemy and drop bombs or other nasty things (ideally they will also fight with the enemy's azhdarchids)? Tech level is late medieval period. Assume that the azhdarchids can be domesticated.

The whole problem with azdarchids is that they are pea-brained.  Sure, if they are able to be domesticated, they can be trained a little, but the problem is that they would be difficult to train to do things that are outside their usual habits.  Next, because they can fly, training them to do things on the wing when their trainers are not with them would be difficult.  How can a pterosaur be trained to drop stuff on the enemy when they don't naturally drop stuff?  It's more likely that they could be trained to swoop, peck and grab... but why would you want to do this in battle, since they're so fragile?
Then there's the problem that if you train your pterosaurs to attack soldiers, they're going to do so... to your soldiers.  The Russians learned this with dogs in WWII, when their anti-tank dogs ran home to their own tanks.  Even particularly smart animals can be hard to train, and azdarchid pterosaurs are not going to be particularly smart.
The solution is actually fairly simple: Child soldiers. History has shown that prior to the 20th century, children as young as around 8 have been recruited to serve in the military, though not necessarily as a front-line combatant.
Because human children are going to be much smarter and easier to train than an azdarchid pterosaur, riders retired due to growing too large would train their younger, smaller replacements to ride and direct the pterosaurs in battle.  A child can easily grasp the concept of directing a flying mount,  identifying the enemy, reporting their location and dropping stuff on them.  Give them a light crossbow, and they can shoot at enemy fliers and their mounts.
Sure, these child soldiers will be at risk... but what's more important?  Winning a war, or protecting all those otherwise useless kids?  In an age where childhood wasn't recognised, and children were thought of as adults who just hadn't finished growing, war is going to be more important.  If they can be given an occupation where their small size is an advantage, all the better.
Additionally, since the body mass of the pterosaur riders is going to be so important, if the pterosaurs have been domesticated for any length of time over a few generations, there could well be a tradition of using people with dwarfism as riders.  Perhaps there could be an entire caste of people with dwarfism who train and ride these pterosaurs.
Just because a dwarf might be able to ride a pterosaur as an adult doesn't mean that adults would be preferred to child riders in battle.  A dwarf child would be an even more valuable rider, since their still lower body mass would mean a higher payload of nasty droppables could be carried aloft.

They can't carry an adult human, but they can carry a human child and enough "nasty droppables" to be effective? Color me skeptical. I rather think the OP is significantly overestimating their potential. Swooping attacks, maybe, but they'll be vulnerable to spears and arrows. Possibly their most effective use is if you can train them to kamikaze dive into and break an enemy line.

Heavy cavalry exists for breaking an enemy line. Being able to drop bombs from a height where you can't be reached is a valuable asset, to say nothing of the psychological impact. Seeing people get blown up nearby and knowing that there's nothing you can do about is a blow to enemy morale.

@IMP9024 I think 111403 was pointing out that "carrying an adult human" and "carrying a human child + an effective quantity of nasty droppables" are reversed in your idea of which is heavier. An effective quantity of nasty droppables will likely weigh much more than the difference between a human child and a human adult, so there's an inconsistency in what they can/can't carry.

A 25kg child rider and a 10 kg bag of flechettes is still less than half of the mass of a 75kg adult rider, and 10kg of flechettes dropped over an army from a kilometre or two up would spoil their day, and in the medieval era, they'd be almost unable to respond effectively.

You're overestimating late medieval technology. Sure, with modern explosives they might still be effective, but they don't have modern explosives. Explosive shells are just becoming a thing (and that only if we're very late medieval), are generally made of cast-iron (i.e. heavy) and they don't yet have a way to time explosions precisely. You get maybe one or two shots, and there's a good chance that the bomb explodes mid-air, the fuse goes out or it hits the ground, breaks apart and goes fizz. It's also going to be really hard to hit anywhere near aiming by hand from a kilometer up.

@IMP9024 "Heavy cavalry exists for breaking an enemy line" - by the late Middle Ages, certainly by the time gunpowder is used for warfare, not really. By this point the cavalry charge has already been countered by pike squares and archers and basically abandoned as a tactic. Incidentally these tactics would also effectively counter pterosaurs; they only work if the birds can be trained to do suicide attacks (pea-sized brains might actually help here).

@user111403 I meant these sorts of flechettes

Yes, I was responding more to the OP's comment. You're not going to see people getting blown up nearby. Flechettes are probably the only other way to have any impact at all, but accuracy from 1-2 km up will be terrible so you'll have to spread them out, and they have to be heavy enough to take out soldiers with armor and shields, so 10 kg probably isn't that many. You'll score a few random hits, if you're lucky, but nothing that will be decisive.

Many prehistoric animals are still around, as I stated in the question. Good luck using a pike on an armored triceratops line charging you down. Also it doesn't have to be bombs, could be incendiary or just kinetic projectiles

@IMP9024 Ah, it's that world :-) Then yeah, heavy cavalry to break lines is a thing. Hot sand is probably not useful - again, weight is limited, and if you drop it from a significant height it's probably not so hot by the time it lands (guessing). Incendiary weapons may be your best bet - I have to admit that I have very little idea of the effectiveness of medieval incendiary weapons relative to the weight you could carry. You also presumably need to somehow keep a flame going.

I also don't know much about medieval incendiaries, but substances like Greek fire, which is largely agreed to be a mixture similar to napalm, could be thrown from catapults or shot from a handheld siphon, so it shouldn't be overly difficult to use. Barring that, there are irritating substances like quicklime, which isn't particularly heavy and can turn into a hot, stinging cloud of gas quickly. I assume that if dropping projectiles from a height proves too inaccurate, low-level bombing runs might be a valid strategy if you can distract the archers (probably with some light cavalry)

Flechettes might still work even if they can't take out armored knights. After all, the vast majority of medieval soldiers will not be able to afford plate armor.

@IMP9024 Flechettes were known to be able to penetrate WWI helmets - and tree branches - so medieval plate isn't going to stop them.

@MontyWild the main problem I see with the Flechettes is relative quantity. Sure, a childsoldier rider may be able to drop 10 kgs of flechettes down on the enemy lines, and kill... I don't know, five footsoldiers. Maybe 20, and wound 30 more? Then he flies back, and gets more ammo - not a quick thing I assume. Also the animal may be exhausted. Meanwhile, the thousands of footsoldiers clash and fight, mostly ignoring that they're 50 less than before. A flying dinosaur will be expensive, so I doubt there will be enough to really make a difference when guys-with-spears are SO much cheaper.

Oxpeckers.
Your civilization has some skill in domestication, and one of their pet species has been the ever-beloved red-billed oxpecker.  Their military has two small training operations, one of which trains young oxpeckers to peck mercilessly at a skin surface whenever - but only when - a human in the distance holds up a large yellow card.  The other does the same with an indigo card.
The two oxpeckers are jessed to the back of the azhdarchid's neck, protected by an iron cage that prevents any well-deserved misbehavior by the captive beast against its tiny tormentors.  By a long, slow process of pavlovian conditioning, it has come to understand that the only way to make the pecking from the left stop is to turn right, and the only way to make the pecking from the right stop is to turn left.
There could be a third color of oxpecker to work the bombs, but for the most part this is not done.  The 'fuse' of a sack hanging well beneath the azhdarchid's feet is simply set on fire, and as it gradually burns, individual incendiaries are let loose.  Some of them may manage to splash flaming oil onto enemy soldiers, but the main purpose is simply to start fires throughout their camp to harass them.  The oxpecker trainers have some cards with various symbols set up - they attempt diligently to debrief their birds concerning enemy troop numbers.  But the astrologers next door are taken as the more definitive authority on the topic.
The pet birds have one more function at camp, the one for which they are best known.  Soldiers found to have committed various small offenses are tied to poles and left within the birdcages.  If the offenses were very small, they are given coverings for their eyes and ears.  An interrogator may stay on hand with his colored cards to ask questions and rate answers, or he might step out and leave a card propped up on a table while he takes dinner in the officers' tent.
